# Would it be a security flaw to pass a URL from javascript to ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, c++, activex

I have an ActiveX control that basically checks if one of our company software is installed, and if not installs it.
(For reasons my boss doesn't want to just download the exe, he wants the ActiveX control to launch the setup.exe).
Now would it be bad if I passed from the javascript the URL & program name ?

Here's my idl interface so far:

```
    //  Primary dispatch interface for CMyAwesomeControl
[ 
    uuid(xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)  
]
dispinterface _DMyAwesomeControl
{
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(1)] LONG IsProgramInstalled(BSTR programName);
        [id(2)] LONG InstallProgram(BSTR installURL);
};
```

I am of course worried about injecting anything malicious into those functions, but since javascript is running on the client side it shouldn't matter right ?
Otherwise I thought I could extract the URL this activeX is running on and make sure it's always our company's domain (but again, hard coding it :/).

I'm sorry in advance if this question makes the more security-savvy people out there pull their hair out :P

EDIT:
Just to add that it would be fine to include the setup.exe + .msi in the resources of the control but that would be a PITA to update.
Otherwise I could include just the setup.exe in the resource and leave the .msi on the server, and store the url in the setup.

Comment: Ok, so someone hacks/injects the page and changes your nice url from `example.com/ourapp.exe` to `nastysite.org/virus.exe`... acceptable?

Comment: does this mean i can launch any program via javascript?

Comment: ok so they have to get onto the server; still better not take the chance then.

Would the program name be fine though ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you sign your exe, and check this signature before running it, I don't see why it would be any different than letting the user download the exe and running it herself.

But make sure your certificate is valid, so you can actually check this on the user's machine (i.e. no self-signing).

Comment: Yes the executable is signed; the boss is being picky about the requirements, I'm just obeying. Apparently IE throws too many warnings at the user, which is a fair enough.
I will still take the safer route and store the setup.exe in the resource of the control.